# Get all nested fields from a certain category

Tags: elasticsearch

I have products in elastic search in the following format with variations. I can do all kind of searches if i know the parameters to search. But due nested subcategories some products have different variations than others.

```
{
                "_index": "ecommerce",
                "_type": "products",
                "_id": "12895",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "Blue Armani Jeans",
                    "slug": "blue-armani-jeans",
                    "price": 200,
                    "sale_price": 0,
                    "vendor_id": 62,
                    "featured": 0,
                    "viewed": 0,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "sku": "arm-jeans",
                    "brand": "",
                    "rating": 0,
                    "active": 0,
                    "vendor_name": "Armani",
                    "category": [
                        "Men Fashion",
                        "Casual Wear"
                    ],
                    "image": "armani-jeans.jpg",
                    "variations": [
                        {
                            "variation_id": "32",
                            "stock": 10,
                            "price": 199,
                            "variation_image": "",
                            "sku": "arm-jeans-11",
                            "Size": "38",
                            "Color": "Blue"
                        },
{
                            "variation_id": "33",
                            "stock": 10,
                            "price": 199,
                            "variation_image": "",
                            "sku": "arm-jeans-12",
                            "Size": "40",
                            "Color": "Blue"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
```

This is just one product, i have hundreds of similar products with different variation parameters. Is it possible to get a list of all the variation parameters from a certain category?

**Required:**
Get all variation parameters from men casual wear ie. color, size, price, waist size etc

Comment: Have you tried a terms aggregation for each of your parameters? If so, what is that solution missing? You would need a search filter for `men casual wear` and then have a terms agg for each of your parameters with a sufficient size param.

Comment: But that would require that i already know all the names of the parameters right? is there a way i could get mapping of all the variation names of selected records

Comment: yes, you need to know things like `size`, `color`, `sku` for this to work. There is no way to make this dynamic in a query.